Android - Face Detection
Is there a way to obtain the image data when using MlKitAnalyzer for face detection ? I am able to draw the bounding box and get all the contours/landmarks but now I need to do rgb calculation on the detected face, for which I can't find a way to access the imageProxy. Any help would be much appreciated.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/mlkit/vision/MlKitAnalyzer.Result
cameraController.setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, MlKitAnalyzer(
            listOf(faceDetectionComponent.getFaceDetector()),
            COORDINATE_SYSTEM_VIEW_REFERENCED,
            cameraExecutor
        ) { result ->
           //draw the bounding box - works well!

           //need access to image data ??
          }

I need to do the below rgb calculation on the detected face but the imageProxy or any other data related to image doesn't seem to be available in MlKitAnalyzer.Result
fun Bitmap.calculateAverageColor(): RGBData {
    var r = 0
    var g = 0
    var b = 0
    val height = this.height
    val width = this.width
    var n = 0.0
    val pixels = IntArray(width * height)
    this.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)
    var i = 0
    while (i < pixels.size) {
        val color = pixels[i]
        r += Color.red(color)
        g += Color.green(color)
        b += Color.blue(color)
        n++
        i += PIXEL_SPACING
    }
    return RGBData(r.toDouble() / n, g.toDouble() / n, b.toDouble() / n)
}


Kindly provide some information about what kind of image info you want to process. Mention  your full code for better understanding.

@VishV I have edited this question with more information and code.

Try my answer and check it's working or not.

Try this solution,
Configure MlKitAnalyzer so you get access to ImageProxy in the result callback and convert ImageProxy to Bitmap and Crop to Face Region.
cameraController.setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, MlKitAnalyzer(
    listOf(faceDetectionComponent.getFaceDetector()),
    COORDINATE_SYSTEM_VIEW_REFERENCED,
    cameraExecutor
) { result ->
    // Get the detected faces (assuming a single face for simplicity)
    val faceList = result.getValue(faceDetectionComponent.getFaceDetector())
    if (faceList != null && faceList.isNotEmpty()) {
        val face = faceList[0] // Get the first detected face
        val boundingBox = face.boundingBox

        // Access the ImageProxy
        val imageProxy = result.imageProxy
        if (imageProxy != null) {
            // Convert ImageProxy to Bitmap
            val bitmap = imageProxy.toBitmap()

            // Crop the Bitmap to the bounding box of the face
            val faceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                boundingBox.left,
                boundingBox.top,
                boundingBox.width(),
                boundingBox.height()
            )

            // Calculate the average color on the cropped face bitmap
            val avgColor = faceBitmap.calculateAverageColor()
            
            // Use avgColor as needed (e.g., log, display, etc.)

            // Don't forget to close the imageProxy
            imageProxy.close()
        }
    }
})

To convert ImageProxy to Bitmap, here’s a utility function:
fun ImageProxy.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val yBuffer = planes[0].buffer
    val uBuffer = planes[1].buffer
    val vBuffer = planes[2].buffer

    val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
    val uSize = uBuffer.remaining()
    val vSize = vBuffer.remaining()

    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize)
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize)

    val yuvImage = YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null)
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out)
    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
}


Sorry, it's not working. When prompted Gemini - that too gave me a similar response.
But result.imageProxy doesn't exist!
